# Windows PE Resources (extension of previous Q.)

Tags: winapi, resources

Based on answer to my previous question, I would like to ask one more on the topic.

To this week, I believed that all the graphics behind windows is actually just code. To create window, menus, button, I thought all is just a function which passes some arguments to OS. But than I found some little bit information about resources. From the very little I found on the internet, I believe that compiler actually looks for specific function that create graphics, and saves them and their data structures into different location in PE file than other code.

That it handles them differently than other code. I want to ask, why? I mean, why not just have functions that call WinAPI for this? Thanks.

EDIT: And how can even for example C compiler tear down program to resources and other code?

I always assumed that any C compiler, even for old one before Windows could generate appropriate code to be run on Windows when supplied by CRT and WinMain function startup code. And just basci knowing of PE structure, just code and data sections....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources are just data.  Data doesn't have any capability of springing to life to alter the appearance of a window.  That requires code that uses the data.  Whether that code lives inside Windows or in your program doesn't really matter.  It is still code.

So, yes, it is all code that gets the job done.  You're doing it right if it is code you don't have to write.  And don't have to maintain.